# Путь к файлу который находиться не в Debug/bin C#

Tags: c#

Возникла проблема с поиском правильного пути к файлу
Environment.CurrentDirectory = C:\Task2\bin\Debug\net5.0\
Папка с файлами которые мне нужны находятся на уровне bin т.е => Task2\Resourses\fileName.json

_fileName = @"..\..\..\Resourses\fileName.json"; написал такой путь

Но сказали что это плохой путь и почитать про AppDomain CurrentDirecoty , и как я понял что через AppDominion мы можешь запускать exe другого проекта , а при помощи CurrentDirrectory получат полный путь до net5.0 , но как это мне поможет найти файл я так и не осознал. Мб есть какая-то библиотека которая помогает найти файл . Буду признателен за любую помощь

Запускать будет другой человек со своего компьютера и у него уже возможно
программа будет не на диске С
Получается известно что будет такой путь Task2//Resourses//fileName а что перед ним не известно

Comment: Рядом с экзешником храните файл, а получайте `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + filename`

Comment: а если нужно чтобы файлы были не в bin(т.е. не с экзешником)  а в Resourses ?

Comment: Познакомьтесь с классом Path, там много полезного.

Comment: Если это .NET 5, то опубликовать проект надо, а не просто собрать. Ресурсы можно вшивать прямо в экзешник.